# Cannot Fetch DynamoDB List of maps

Tags: c#, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

So I.m storing data in dynamoDb as a list of maps. I can easily store the data just by using SaveAsync(ClassObject). But I cant fetched the data. This is the data I'm trying to fetch. But in the database it is Storing with AttributeValue such as [m:{s:{subservice : writer}}]

```
{
    "Column" : "Writing",
    "Requirements" : [
                        {
                            "subService" : "writer",
                            "description" : "info why writer"
                        },
                        {
                            "subService" : "blogger",
                            "description" : "info why blogger"
                        }
                    ]
}
```

```
            JArray req = new JArray();

            string columnValue = data["Column"].ToObject<string>();

            ScanRequest request = FilterRequest(tableName, "Column", columnValue );
//FilterRequest is just a scanrequest
            var response = await dbClient.ScanAsync(request);

            var serviceRequirements = response.Items[0];

            foreach (var requirement in serviceRequirements["Requirements"])
            {
                JObject subCat = new JObject();
                
                subCat.Add("subService", requirement["subService"].S.ToString());
                subCat.Add("description", requirement["description"].S.ToString());
                

                req.Add(requirement);

            }

            return req;
```

I'm stuck at this for two days. And I cannot find any reference to my problem. Im just simply want to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took lot of hit and trial...but it works now
just want to share the answer, hope it helps someone

```
JArray req = new JArray();

            string columnValue = data["Column"].ToObject<string>();

            ScanRequest request = FilterRequest(tableName, "Column", columnValue );
//FilterRequest is just a scanrequest

            var response = await dbClient.ScanAsync(request);


            var serviceRequirements = response.Items[0]["Requirements"].L.ToArray();

            var out1 = serviceRequirements[0].M.Values.ToArray();

            foreach(var element in serviceRequirements)
            {
                JObject subCat = new JObject();

                subCat.Add("subService",element.M.Values.ToArray()[0].S.ToString());
                subCat.Add("description",element.M.Values.ToArray()[1].S.ToString());
                req.Add(subCat);
            }

            return req;
```

this returns

```
                    [
                        {
                            "subService" : "writer",
                            "description" : "info why writer"
                        },
                        {
                            "subService" : "blogger",
                            "description" : "info why blogger"
                        }
                    ]
```